# Python: function returning exec is returning nothing

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, function

Here is my MWE (which looks stupid):

```
def somefunc(a0,a1,b1,a2,b2):
    first = 'a0'
    rest = ['+a{}+b{}'.format(i,i) for i in range(1, int((len(locals())-1) / 2)
    for element in rest:
        first+=element
    return exec(first)
```

Basically I want to create an expression without having to type it in. So I use list comprehension with strings and then I execute.

However if I try
`somefunct(1,1,1,1,1)` I get absolutely nothing..

Comment: Assuming you fixed the unbalanced brackets in `rest`, and you replaced `exec` with `eval`, you might find that your `first` string did not end up as you intended. You should at least print it out and see what it says.

Comment: Why is it a duplicate of that one? i don't even know what eval does

Comment: @Euler_Salter So go read the answers to that question and find out